# MacBook 2007 charger

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe, charger

I have a MacBook I bought in 2007 and the charger recently died on me. (I'm assuming the computer itself is still working).

I did some research and ordered from Amazon a Magsafe1 60W charger, but when it arrived the connecter is too large for the port.

Any ideas what the correct charger should be? These are the details of the MacBook, purchased in Aug 2007

- 13-inch MacBook (White) - 2.16GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- Part Number: MB062
- Keyboard (English) & Mac OS (English)
  Country kit
- 2.16GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- SuperDrive 8x (DVD +R DL/DVD RW/CD-RW)
- 1GB 667 DDR2 - 2x512MB SO-DIMMs
- 120GB Serial ATA drive (5400rpm)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact charger you purchased?

Comment: Hi there - thanks for replying! This is the one I bought that was too big : https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B00K0BQIQ4/ref=pd_aw_sim_147_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=F87KA55WJN3EAA5ZH51S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter you bought is a MagSafe 2, and that is why it's too wide. Since you bought the first one on Amazon, here is the link for one that will work. It is thicker but narrower side-to-side: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-MagSafe-Adapter-Non-Retail-Packaging/dp/B00K0BQG9I/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1471805469&sr=8-2&keywords=magsafe+60w

The power adapters with the original MagSafe connectors come in either L- or T-varieties. Both adapters will fit your MacBook. The reasons for why they have gone back and forth are beyond the scope of your question, but there's no electrical difference and no difference in the physical connection to the MacBook.

[image: MagSafe 2]

Comment: If a response here answered your question, please mark it as the accepted solution. Thanks!

Comment: The charger arrived today and it was the right one - thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

#### Your Mac came with the 60W Adapter

The adapter that Apple shipped with your Mac was the 60W Magsafe 2 with "T" Connector.  From [Apple's Support site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700):

[image: Apple MagSafe chart]

#### Get the 85W Adapter Instead

That said, I would get an [Apple 85W MagSafe 2 adapter](http://radnex.us/Apple_85w_magsafe-2) instead of the 60W.  You will have more versatility if you decide to upgrade your MacBook to a different model down the road.  You won't do any damage, 85W just means that's the maximum power draw the adapter will support, not that it will push that amount to your computer.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for replying! I saw this option but was a little nervous as my original connector wasn't a 't' shape. Will that make any difference?

Comment: It was either the "T" or the "L" shaped connectors for that generation of MacBook.  As far as making a difference, generally speaking, if it fits, it won't damage your Mac (will it have enough power to charge/turn on is a different story).  If it doesn't fit, there's nothing it can do damage anything.

Comment: Bought the MagSafe 1 85W charger, and it worked.